# Error: Could not find dependency Package[php5-cli] for Exec[download composer]

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony2 project with this [Vagrant](https://github.com/sqmk/vagrant-debian-php-vm) virtual machine. The problem comes when I try to run the environment with `vagrant up` commandand it outputs the following:

```
$vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'debian-php-dev'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
cause things such as shared folders to not work properly. If you see
shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
your host and reload your VM.

Guest Additions Version: 4.2.10
VirtualBox Version: 4.3
[default] Setting hostname...
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Exporting NFS shared folders...
Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
Password:
[default] Mounting NFS shared folders...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0
[default] Running provisioner: puppet...
Running Puppet with site.pp...
stdin: is not a tty
Error: Could not find dependency Package[php5-cli] for Exec[download composer]
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

puppet apply --hiera_config /vagrant/config/hiera.yaml --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0' --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests/site.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
Error: Could not find dependency Package[php5-cli] for Exec[download composer]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
  include php::cli
```

To the `manifests / site.pp` file just below `include php::dev` on line 70

The error is pretty self explanatory - `the php5-cli` package is missing from this particular **Vagrant** setup that you have chosen to use... adding it in is easy and everything else should work... as long as there are no other modules or packages missing.